# What are best practices to change a Python module's name while keeping backwards compatibility?

Tags: python, python-packaging

I wrote a Python module used by various other people. If I decide that the module's name should change (not saying this is necessarily a good idea, let's just assume that a decision was made that it needs to be renamed).

Is there a canonical way to ensure that users can still use the old name, so that both `import newname; newname.foo()` and `import oldname; oldname.foo()` work and invoke the same underlying code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not the canonical way, but it is a brainstorming idea.

You can create a new Python module that serves as a wrapper and simply imports everything from the old module. Users can then import from this new module, and it will forward all requests to the original module.

```
# wrapper_module.py

from oldname import *
```

With this approach, users can now import the module using the new name:

```
import wrapper_module as newname
```

And they can still access the functions and classes using the old name:

```
import oldname

# Both of these will work and call the same underlying code:
newname.foo()
oldname.foo()
```

Using this will help maintain backward compatibility while allowing you to transition to the new module name gradually.